# Rest assure basic get query getting error

Tags: rest-assured

I am trying to check basic rest assured get method and getting below error.
Using the below version: rest-assured-4.1.1-dist.zip

Code:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class Basics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Testing");
        RestAssured.basePath = "https://maps.googleapis.com";
        given().
        param("location", "-33.8670522,151.1957362").
        param("radius", "500").
        param("key", "AIzaSyDAyGVdrax3PwjtaJyQvlajVpgt46HBEWo").
        when().
        get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").
        then().assertThat().statusCode(200);

    }

}
```

Output:

Testing

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>     at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2054)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:451)
>     at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1450)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)    at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1199)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)    at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
>     at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>     at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)     at
>   io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
>     at
>   io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
>     at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
>     at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1654)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)    at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1660)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)    at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:171)
>     at
>   io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
>     at Basics.main(Basics.java:15)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use of `RestAssured.baseURI` variable, not `RestAssured.basePath`.
This will work:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class Basics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //You need to set baseURI here, not basePath
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://maps.googleapis.com";
        given().
        param("location", "-33.8670522,151.1957362").
        param("radius", "500").
        param("key", "value").
        when().
        get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").
        then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
    }
}
```